# UpdatePanel resetting object to inital state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an application that I am currently writing that works by iterating through nodes, and then updating the page with the information of the current node. I have an UpdatePanel in the page which contains a label, textbox, and a button. The label lists the currently available children of the current node, the user enters in which child they want to go to into the textbox, and then hits the submit button. I set the new value of the node in the submit button's event handler.

Here's my problem: Every time I enter in which node I want to navigate to, the object resets its value to the value it was initially initialized to. I have even put this same code into a Windows Form to validate that it's working correctly to iterate through my tree, and it works as it should, so I know my problem is AJAX-related.

This is the first app that I have written using AJAX, so I am still in the process of learning how it works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have Googled and searched SO through and through.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="question" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Submit_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

And the C#:

```
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ans = int.Parse(answer.Text);

        if (!current.ChildIDs.Contains(ans))
        {
            return;
        }
        current = tree.Node(ans);
        question.Text = current.Question;
    }
```

current is the current node, which has a public ArrayList of all of its children's IDs. tree is the NodeTree I have; calling Node just returns the new node. Both current and Tree get initialized in the Page_Load event, and that only fires once (when the page is first loaded).

It's really pretty simply code; I'm just having difficulty understanding why the AJAX isn't working correctly.

Comment: Without seeing code, I'm shooting in the dark, but I suspect that your issue doesn't have to do with the UpdatePanel.  Try this: Remove or disable the update panel temporarily.  See if your code works using old fashioned post backs.  If it doesn't, your issue isn't with the update panel.  Also, make sure your init code is not firing on postback... unless it is supposed to.

Comment: Everything is initialized on Page_Load. I am under the assumption that that means that it is only run once, when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Page_Load runs on every call or postback.  You need to test for Page.IsPostBack for code you only want to run on the initial Page_Load.

Comment: I just checked again, and you are correct. All the pieces are now starting to come together... What event handler can I use that is triggered only when the page is initially loaded?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. An UpdatePanel's Init event is only triggered when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have even put this same code into a
>   Windows Form to validate that it's
>   working correctly to iterate through
>   my tree, and it works as it should, so
>   I know my problem is AJAX-related.

It sounds like you're expecting ASP.NET to remember what the object `current` is between requests, since that's how Windows forms applications work.

**Web applications are stateless** - after each request, ASP.NET discards all your variables. To access the variable during a subsequent request, you have to either:

1) Send enough data with the request to reconstruct the variable. You can do this using a querystring parameter or an HTML form value (the hidden fields another response mentioned).

2) Save the variables in a `Session` store (which can be in-memory or backed by a database).

3) Store the value in a coookie.

Of these three, it's easiest to show you how to use `Session`, given what you've shared in your question. However, beware: session has its risks - by default, ASP.NET session objects are stored in-memory, and it's a potential security hazard. But here's how you should be able to get your application to work.

```
// In your Page_Load code that initializes your 'current' variable

// When the user first requests the page, create a new Node
if (! this.IsPostBack) 
{
    Node current = new Node(); //
    Session("currentNode") = current;
} 
// When the user clicks a button on the page (posts), use the
// node in session instead
else 
{
    current = Session("currentNode");
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I assumed because it was AJAX that the object would be stored throughout the time I was on the same page. Thanks for the info, I'll looking into using a Session store or cookies.

Comment: I got it working using Sessions. Thanks so much for the help; I was tearing my hair out.

Comment: ViewState is another option for storing the current node if your tree is used on a single page.  Also, UpdatePanels generally function the same as a full postback in terms of how they do or don't maintain state.

Comment: True on both counts, though it's important to note that ViewState is a specialized case of option #1 (since it's transmitted via a hidden form field).

Answer (score 1):

When you update non-form elements in the browser (labels, literals, etc.), .NET is unable to see any of the changes you've made.

Try adding a hidden input for each label that records the new value.  Then within the method you have wired up to the button's OnClick event, do something like this:

```
myLabel.Text = myHiddenInput.value;
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean by a hidden input. I tried creating a new object to temporarily store the new value of the current node, but it too gets reset. For some reason, on every post back the current node gets reset to the value it was given when it was first initialized.

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but this would work: `<input type="hidden" id="txtHidden" runat="server" />`.  This would be available to you in your codebehind as a `HtmlInputHidden` object.

Comment: Sorry, the initial question didn't have the code sample or mention that a TreeView was involved.  I'll post another answer.

Comment: Just tried that, both inside and outside the UpdatePanel. The value gets reset just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to tell the updatepanel to update itself.  Try this:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ans = int.Parse(answer.Text);

    if (!current.ChildIDs.Contains(ans))
    {
        return;
    }
    current = tree.Node(ans);
    question.Text = current.Question;

    UpdatePanel.Update();

}
```

Comment: You might want to give that updatepanel a more unique id to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Already tried that and set the UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to Conditional (instead of Always). Didn't change anything. Sorry, probably should have mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: Does the `<Triggers>` section contain `<asp:asyncpostbackcontrol ID="TreeViewId" />`?